# There always exists $x\in S^1$ such that $f(x)=f(-x)$ subject to

Tags: general-topology, continuity

> Let $S^1$ ={$(x,y)\in \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}: x^2 + y^2 =1$}. Observe that if $x=(x_1, x_2)\in S^1 $ then $-x= (-x_1 , -x_2) \in S^1$. Let $f:S^1 \to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function. Prove that there exists a $x\in S^1$ such that $f(x)=f(-x)$.

This question is from an assignment in my topology course for section connected spaces and compact spaces.

I am not able to make much progress on this. $S^1$ is connected and $f$ is continuous implies $f(S^1)$ is also connected in $\mathbb{R}$.But I am unable to make required progress relating to $f$.

Comment: A hint is to consider the function $g(x) = f(x) - f(-x)$. The image of $g$ is also connected and you want to show that $0$ is in the image. Can you see what you must do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put $g(x) = f(x) - f(-x)$.  Observe that $g(-x) = -g(x)$. If $g$ is identically zero, you are done.  Otherwise, $g$'s image will contain a positive and a negative number.  Since $S^1$ is connected, $g$'s  image is connected.  We conclude that $g$ has a zero at some point $x$; for such an $x$, $f(x) = f(-x).$